# Multiple columns in where clause giving syntax error

Tags: android, sql-update, android-sqlite

I am facing a problem in updating a table with multiple columns in where clause of the `db.update` in sqlite.

Below is what I have tried but not accepting and showing syntax error.

```
db.getWritableDatabase().update(tablename, update((buy+dupbuy)), (column2+"=? and"+ column3+"=?"),(new String[] {getdate}+" and"+new String[] {stockname}));
```

In above query

1. First parameter is tablename to be updated.
2. second parameter is value to be updated which will point to another class update method where I wrote content values for updating the table
3. Major one third part is parameters I need to pass in where clause.

but giving syntax error

`The method update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, ContentValues, String, String)`

How can I declare multiple columns in where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
db.getWritableDatabase().update(tablename, update((buy+dupbuy)), (column2+"=? and"+ column3+"=?"),(new String[] {getdate}+" and"+new String[] {stockname}));
```

to

```
db.getWritableDatabase().update(tablename, update((buy+dupbuy)), (column2+"=? and "+ column3+"=?"),(new String[] {getdate,stockname}));
```

Add a space after the `"and"` in the `WHERE` clause and you need to pass a `String[]` and not `String` in the `whereArgs` parameter. Currently you are passing a `String`

Answer (score 1):

Change the stretch code:

```
db.getWritableDatabase().update(tablename, update((buy+dupbuy)), (column2+"=? and"+ column3+"=?"),(new String[] {getdate}+" and"+new String[] {stockname}));
```

To

```
db.getWritableDatabase().update( tablename, update(buy+dupbuy), column2 + " = ? and " + column3 + " = ?", new String[]{ getdate, stockname } );
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. it is not allowing me to run at all so I think placing a log is also not useful.but trying your suggesstion will update soon.

Comment: Nope till the same issue... Error: The method update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, ContentValues, String, String)

Comment: When I was typing my answer did not see the response from @Apoorv. My answer is almost equal to him, except for readability. You put parentheses in certain places by nothing.